# How do I add the effect of sampling rate to a difference equation?

Tags: c++, integration, transfer, sampling, differential-equations

I want to implement the difference equations below to design an accumulator and a differentiator:

Accumulator:
`y[n] = y[n-1] + x[n]`, where `y[n]`is the n'th output and `x[n]` is n'th the input.

Differentiator:
`y[n] = x[n] - x[n-1]`, where `y[n]`is the n'th output and `x[n]` is n'th the input.

Accumulator:

```
double xn, yn, yn1 = 0;
std::vector<double> InputVector = GetInputVector(), OutputVector;
for(int i=0; i<MAX_NUM_INPUTS; i++)
{
    if (IsFinished()) break;
    yn = yn1 + xn;
    yn1 = yn;
    OutputVector.push_back(yn);
}
```

Differantiator:

```
double xn, yn, xn1 = 0;
std::vector<double> InputVector = GetInputVector(), OutputVector;
for(int i=0; i<MAX_NUM_INPUTS; i++)
{
    if (IsFinished()) break;
    yn = xn - xn1;
    xn1 = xn;
    OutputVector.push_back(yn);
}
```

The data in the input vector is originated from a continuous time signal. In other words, it is sampled to obtain this discrete time signal. And it has a sampling rate T<sub>d</sub>.

When I increase the sampling rate of the input signal, the amplitude of the output of the accumulator. This is expected since there happens to be more samples to differentiate. On the other side, with the increasing sampling rate, the output amplitude of the differentiator decreases. The amplitudes of both differentiator and integrator are correct (at the values which the math says they must be) when the sampling rate is unitary (i.e.; 1.0 samples/second).

My question is;
How do I nullify the effect of the sampling rate at the output vector?

My general question is;
Suppose that I obtain a difference equation from an arbitrary causal discrete-time transfer function `H(z)`. The difference equation can be anything in this case. How do I nullify the effect of the sampling rate in this general case?

(Please refer to this forum thread for more detail:
[Relevant forum thread](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=463283))

Comment: Note that your difference equations will not give very good results with real world signals, as they are susceptible to small DC offsets and noise. For real world applications you need to tailor the frequency response of both differentiators and integrators.

Comment: Read up on Z-transform. You can can easily go from Laplace transfer equation to the Z-transform and this then leads to the correct difference equations for the system that you are modelling. You will find this information in Control theory books like Otaki's.

Comment: @T33C: When we apply bilinear transformation to a continuous time transfer function, we introduce a sampling rate term during the transformation; s=(2/Td)*(1-1/z)/(1+1/z). Td is the sampling period. Bilinear transformed discrete time signals work nicely, because they have Td term in them. But how do I add this Td into originally discrete time systems (the ones which are not transformed from continuous time, the ones that are designed in discrete time from the start)?

Answer (score 0):

For differentiator: To get same results for various sampling intervals divide the output `y` by Td.

For accumulator (integrator): Multiply input `x` by Td.

Comment: That may work for accumulator, but for differentiator it wouldn't; because the output of the differentiator is already attenuated more than it should be. Rather then finding solutions for accumulator and differentiator cases, I'm looking for a general solution for any difference equation.

Comment: Have you tried that? Dividing by Td is definitely the correct way if I understand you question correctly. You get an equation y[n]=(x[n]-x[n-1])/Td.

Comment: No need to try, because I know you are right. But what I'm asking is a general method for normalizing output amplitude.